# Парсинг JSON внутри CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

имеется csv следующего формата:

> "ID"|"service"|"attribute"|"Start_Time"|"Stop_Time"
>
> "664445"|"UP"|"|"{"BW_DL":"BW_2"}"|"20170306211916+0000"|"20170306214916+0000"
>   "664633"|"UP_PLUS"|"{"MA":"MA4","BW_DL":"BW_24"}"|""|""

И следующий код:

```
def csv_work():

dump_obj = open(dump_file, 'r')

dump_reader = csv.DictReader(dump_obj, delimiter='|')

    for line in dump_reader:
        if line["attribute"] != '':
            print(line["attribute"])
```

На выходе из JSON съедаются первые две двойных кавычки:

> {BW_DL":"BW_2"}" {MA":"MA4","BW_DL":"BW_24"}"

Escape char тут не подходит - внутрь JSON \ перед каждой кавычкой добавлять не выйдет.

Как можно поправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставьте кавычки вокруг ключей и значений в json, остальные удалите:

```
ID|service|attribute|Start_Time|Stop_Time
664445|UP||{"BW_DL":"BW_2"}|20170306211916+0000|20170306214916+0000
664633|UP_PLUS|{"MA":"MA4","BW_DL":"BW_24"}||
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Если csv выглядит следующим образом:

```
"ID"|"service"|"attribute"|"Start_Time"|"Stop_Time"

"664445"|"UP"|"{"BW_DL":"BW_2"}"|"20170306211916+0000"|"20170306214916+0000"
"664633"|"UP_PLUS"|"{"MA":"MA4","BW_DL":"BW_24"}"|""|""
```

то применяя следующую функцию (в 2.7):

```py
import csv
import json

def csv_work(dump_file):
    dump_obj = open(dump_file, 'r')
    dump_reader = csv.DictReader(dump_obj, delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for line in dump_reader:
        print line
        new_line = {x.strip('\"'): y.strip('\"') for x, y in line.iteritems()}
        print json.loads(new_line['attribute'])

csv_work(r'qw.csv')
```

можно получить:

```py
{u'BW_DL': u'BW_2'}
{u'BW_DL': u'BW_24', u'MA': u'MA4'}
```